# Error when compiling

Tags: errors, compiling

Hi all I get this error message and I don't know what to do[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  For future questions, please copy and paste text instead of posting a screen shot.  Images are harder for people to read, and impossible for search engines to read.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to add `article` or any other class

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately it gives the same error regardless

Comment: @Maarten192000 Have you already installed a TeX distribution (usually [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive), [MiKTeX](https://www.miktex.org) or [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex)) or only a LaTeX editor?

Comment: Thanks I needed to reinstall MiKTeX!